# How to make a rounded edged art board in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard

I am trying to create a save the date invitation. The bride wants the invitations to have rounded edges of about .5 inches. Is this something I can do to the art board itself, or do I just create a rounded edge rectangle, put my art on that, and specify to the printers how to cut the art?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't round an artboard.

You could use a rounded rectangle, but you *shouldn't*.

Corner rounding on the printed piece is handled *after* the piece is printed and when it is being folded and cut.

Design with square edges and don't do *anything* to indicate rounded corners. Then tell the printer you want the corners rounded when they print it. (note, this *may* increase printing costs.)

Comment: To Scott (can't comment yet, sorry): What if it's for web/devices and not print? Surely it's usable there; how **can** you make your artboard corners rounded, or rather, fit the shape of a rounded rectangle?

Comment: If you want rounded edges for electronic devices you can set a round edge rectangle that fills the art board and export as a PNG to preserve transparency. You still can't make a rounded art board.

Comment: @yoaquim **all** digital images are rectangular. All of them. You can only use transparency in areas you want to *appear* absent. You can't round artboards. You *can* create a rounded objects and save it with transparency so the corners *appear* not to be there.

Answer (score 0):

Scott is correct that AI artboards cannot be rounded. If you are creating for web, I would suggest rounding corners in CSS, so design as you would in print with square corners. If you are creating for devices… I don't know. BUT, if you must round corners in AI, you do that to a rounded corner rectangle (or use live corners as in recent versions). From there, you create a PNG or SVG with transparency.

If creating a PNG, you can “Save for web” and *uncheck* the “Clip to artboard” check box (near the sizing options). If creating an SVG, it is important to use an artboard at the exact width & height (in pixels) as your graphic.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution and welcome to GraphicDesign! Let us know if you have any questions